# Reading a csv file using C#/ADO into a dataset on an asp.net page, but a field with commas enclosed in double quotes are still "split"

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I have the following code to read a csv file:

```
//Create connection string to Excel
string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadDir"].ToString() + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"";

//Create Connection to Excel
OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [updatefile.csv]", excelConnection);
adapter.Fill(dsUpdate);
```

My csv contains the following:

```
prde,cost,ourestimate,floors,psize,commdate

Mixed-Use Development,$5 000 000,"$5,000,000",5,,2014
```

However, when the code above gets to the adapter.Fill(dsUpdate), the resulting dataset comes up with the following columns and values:

1. prde:  Mixed-Use Development
2. cost:  $5 000 000
3. ourestimate:  5
4. floors:  0
5. psize:  0
6. commdate: 5

Basically, it split the "$5,000.000" into 3 columns with values of 5, 0 and 0 (the 000 were converted to 0).

I have also tried the following connection strings, but the results are the same:

```
string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadDir"].ToString() + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=CSVDelimited\"";

string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadDir"].ToString() + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"";
```

I'm not sure what else I might be doing wrong.  As far as I can tell those are correct based on what I see on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/net-txtreader-for-text-files/  Make sure it's identifying the quotes to cancelling out delimiters internally

Answer (score -1):

Before doing a string.split, run the line through a Regex.Replace to replace any commas in the pattern "$......" with spaces or even an empty string, seeing as you're likely to want to convert it to a decimal value.

Comment: That's not the exact pattern to use, but you get the idea ?

Comment: I don't actually use a string.split (I have not mentioned it anywhere in my post), as that would not care whether the commas were enclosed in double quotes or not.  As noted in my question, I read the csv into a dataset.

Comment: I can see you're not doing that; however as your approach is not giving you the results you want, I'm *suggesting* a different one.

Comment: Ah, apologies then.  I will keep that in mind if I am allowed to go that route.

Comment: Hey no apology needed dude. I've not tried importing CSV using your approach but I'm guessing there's not much you can do about the internal implementation of OleDbDataAdapter.Fill - and this is what seems to be causing the problem. Hence I'd try a different approach, even if it means a bit more work.